# tableHeaderView interactive part disappear

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

This is my tableHeaderView code：

```
private lazy var headerView:ZczzHeaderView = {
        let obj = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ZczzHeaderView", owner: nil, options: nil).first as? ZczzHeaderView
        //        obj?.delegete = self
        obj?.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.width,80)
        return obj!
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView


    }
```

[image]

My tableHeaderView is divided into two parts. The interaction effect of the second part disappears.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you defined the height of HeaderView using `heightForHeaderInSection`. If not then please do define the header height

Comment: heightForHeaderInSection is set for section header hight , not tableHeaderView

Answer (score 0):

I know  I create a nib file by
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJuxF.png)
view(the second)  not Empty(the third) 
this is the reason
although I not know
the difference Empty(the third)  Drag a UiView  and View(the second)
Please know that the people educated me